# Moving back at forth while in the for loop

Tags: python

I've got an interesting problem to solve. How do I change direction of iteration (go reverse) whilst in iteration ? Let me explain. I've got list like this:

```
a = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

and say, if the fourth element contains the letter 'r' go back one step
and add to the element before that number 3 until the length of the element is less than or equal 10. Something like this:

```
for index, element in enumerate(a):
    if 'r' in element and len(a[index-1]) <= 10:
        # go back solution comes here
        a[index-1] += '3'
    else:
        continue
```

It's quite obvious why I can't just stick with `a[index-1] += '3'`. Because that won't track the position of the iteration, right. Because the program needs to know how many times it needs to go back and extend the element.

Is there Pythonic solution to this ? I'm aware of `range(10, 0, -1)` and `reverse(<iterator>)` but that won't help in this case.

Comment: What is your actual goal? Hacking a for loop to go back and forth is probably not a good solution to that.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I'm gonna have to come up with something new.

Comment: As great as for loops are you can't just go backwards in the middle of iteration.

Comment: You may be looking for a while loop...? With a while loop you can control the position in your list that you are at for each 'iteration'

Comment: Convert it to a dict, with the keys of the same value, then you can go back and forth via the key.

Comment: @mr_incredible Why not just `a[index-1] += '3' * (10 - len(a[index-1]))`? As long as you have the index, you can always refer to earlier elements by calculating an offset, so I don't really see what the problem is. There is no need to literally change the direction of the iterator.

Comment: @ekhumoro good point.

Comment: @ekhumoro  I'm with you on this. Your way work and as turned out the code I shared in edited post also worked without doing flips in the air with for loop itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you were looking for:

```py
a = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
count = 0
while count < len(a):
    element = a[count]
    #print('in loop')
    if 'r' in element and count > -1 and len(a[count-1]) <= 10:
        # go back solution comes here
        #print('going back')
        a[count-1] += '3'
        count -= 1
        #print('done')
        print(a)
    else:
        #print('not found')
        count += 1
        continue
```

Output:

```
['one', 'two3', 'three', 'four']
['one', 'two33', 'three', 'four']
['one', 'two333', 'three', 'four']
['one', 'two3333', 'three', 'four']
['one', 'two33333', 'three', 'four']
['one', 'two333333', 'three', 'four']
['one', 'two3333333', 'three', 'four']
['one', 'two33333333', 'three', 'four']
['one', 'two33333333', 'three3', 'four']
['one', 'two33333333', 'three33', 'four']
['one', 'two33333333', 'three333', 'four']
['one', 'two33333333', 'three3333', 'four']
['one', 'two33333333', 'three33333', 'four']
['one', 'two33333333', 'three333333', 'four']
```

Comment: Will this not create an infinite loop? It will find the `r` in `three` and go back one step, then next step it will come forwards and find the `r` in `three` again.

Comment: No nevermind. Once `two` is longer than 10 characters it will get past it. This works

Comment: It will only add to a string if its length is less than or equal to 10.

Answer (score 2):

I guess Sid's answer solved the issue. I just wanted to point out that the `while` loop isn't really neccessary. In Python, you may multiply strings: `3*"hi "` will return `hi hi hi`, and the final length of each element is known (10).. Below is a neat/ugly (depending on who you ask) one-liner that yields the same result as Sid's solution.

```
a = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']

char = "3" # char to add to chosen elements in list
length = 10 # the final char-length after adding the chars to list elements
trigger = "r" # char to trigger the adding of new chars.

b = [x if (i==len(a)-1 or trigger not in a[i+1]) else x+(char*(length-len(x))) for i, x in enumerate(a)]

print(b) # ['one', 'two3333333', 'three33333', 'four']
```

Comment: Your one-liner is fine, but when it comes to one-liner solutions I do look at readability. So even if the one-liner works if it's hard to read or comprehend what it does just by looking at it I'm not gonna use it because I know what it does **now** but if I see it in month's time again I won't have a clue what it does unless I drop a comment next to it. So readability counts. But you do get points for coming up with one-liner that does the job.

Comment: @mr_incredible I completely agree: readability trumps almost everything. After all, *"premature optimization is the root of all evil"*. However, when you've read some thousands lines of python code, you'll realize that this line isn't that complicated at all... I posted as an addtion to Sid's answer. By no means do I claim mine to be better. I just wanted to point out that python's list comprehensions should a way of life <3

Comment: Don't worry about not getting a green tick. You're getting upvotes which counts for something here on SO. One came from me because you took time to pitch in and you're the only one who came up with a one-liner. I've not read thousands lines of Python code but I do have my share that's expanding ...

Answer (score 0):

```
for index, element in enumerate(a):
    if 'r' in element and len(a[index-1]) <= 10:
        while len(a[index-1]) <= 10:
            a[index-1] += '3'
    else:
        continue
```

Perhaps not the most Pythonic way to do it but I do find it quite elegant. Depends who you ask.